# Updating a password using user_save always sends an email

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using the user_save function in Drupal 6 to update a user's password on a custom module.  The issue is that calling the user_save function to update the password causes Drupal to send the user an email stating that their account has been activated.

Anyone know of a way to stop Drupal from sending out this email?

Answer (score 1):

By looking into Drupal 7 Documentation [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/7) try following.

$conf['password_reset'] = FALSE;

Following other options are available, just in case you wish to use any other option.

- 'register_admin_created': Welcome message for user created by the admin.
- 'register_no_approval_required': Welcome message when user self-registers.
- 'register_pending_approval': Welcome message, user pending admin approval.
- 'password_reset': Password recovery request.
- 'status_activated': Account activated.
- 'status_blocked': Account blocked.
- 'cancel_confirm': Account cancellation request.
- 'status_canceled': Account canceled.

Comment: I am using Drupal 6 (not 7), but anyways, you are referring to _user_mail_notify which is already called within user_save.  I am trying to find out how to stop Drupal from sending out an email when invoking user_save.